# Default extension factor of xlim / ylim in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

**Question**

When creating a plot with `ggplot` the limits for the axis are determined automatically to cover the whole range of points to be plotted. To avoid that points are on the edge of the plotting area `xlim` and `ylim` are extended by a (additive/multiplicative/both?) factor. My question is how to determine the default value for this expansion?

**Example**

Look at this example:

```
library(ggplot2)
d <- data.frame(x = 1:10)
qplot(x, x, data = d) + scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(0.55, 1:10, 10.45)) +
     scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(0.55, 1:10, 10.45))
```

You can see that the x/y-axes range approximately (exactly?) from 0.55 - 10.45. So now my question is how does `ggplot` determine these limits? Is it simply something like `extendrange(d$x)` or is it determined differently?

**Background**

I want to force one of my plots to use the same range for the x and the y axis. I know I can do that via `xlim` and `ylim`. But for consistency reasons I want to use exactly the same extension factor as `ggplot` is using per default, such that the plots look similiar when it comes to distance from the borders of the plotting area.

Comment: @hrbrmstr It's actually in `coord_expand_defaults.default`, `(0,0.6)` for discrete scales and `(0.05,0)` for continuous scales, I believe.